# I am unable to access /admin/dashboard on the main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange

For some time now, accessing `/admin/dashboard` on the main site has resulted in an "oops" error. Moderation requests are piling up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment (`rev 4093`)